# Why is Feedfetcher-Google visiting my website if Google Reader and iGoogle services have been discountinued?

Tags: rss, feed, google-feed-api

I get this user agent `Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=17582163705065100568)` in my logs coming from a google domain even if there is no way you could read rss feeds through google and still I see there is 1 subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the [Google Feed API has been deprecated](http://blog.superfeedr.com/google-feed-api-alternative/), it's still possible that some people are subscribed to your feed(s) thru that? Also, don't forget that [Google uses RSS as a discovery mechanism](https://www.seroundtable.com/pubsubhubbub-google-20515.html) for its search engine.

Comment: My website is weeks new so I don't think it's possible that people are subscribed to my feed and the google recommendation on using PubSubHubbub and rss feeds for quick indexing doesn't explain why the visit comes from http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html.

Comment: Hum... Again, google uses feeds for discovery (whether the feeds uses PuSH or not!). Let's say they crawled your site once, and then found the feed. They now use the feed (and fetch it regularly) to identify new pages.

Comment: The official answer from google would be that they never use feeds for crawling and this is the reason feedfetcher doesn't obey the robots.txt rules - even it is actually a bot, his visit would have been manually/intentionally by a humam. This is why i believe this visit was generated by a real person that added my feed to google feedfetcher "somehow". I managed to replicate the same visit using https://developers.google.com/feed/ and indeed I got a visit from the same UA and some random google domain without the "1 subscribers; feed-id=17582163705065100568" part.